# Python Linked List how value gets assigned

Tags: python, linked-list

Below is a code that divides each number of the node by 10. For example, node = 2->3->3, output would be 0.2->0.3->0.3.

However I am confused on why `self.head.next` gets updated each time given it's `cur` that receive the change. Suppose `a=1,b=2` and we make a(`cur`)=b(`self.head`), if we change the value of a to 3, that wouldn't affect b, b is still 2. Therefore I couldn't understand why changing `cur` would affect `self.head.next`. Thank you!

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value=value
        self.next=next

class linkedlist(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.next=None
    def test(self,List):
        self.head=node(0)
        cur=self.head
        while List:
            s=List.value/10
            cur.next=node(s)
            cur=cur.next
            List=List.next if List else 0
        return self.head.next
```

Suppose below is the input:

```
 a=node(2)
 a=node(2,a)
 a=node(3,a)
 c=linkedlist()
```

Below is the output:

```
c.test(a).value=0.3
c.test(a).next.value=0.2
c.test(a).next.next.value=0.2
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output? By the way, you can use `List.head` instead of only `List` to make the code more readable. As of now, I see that your list contains only nodes with `0` as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused on why self.head.next gets updated each time given it's cur that receive the change

That is because, at least in the first iteration of the loop, `self.head` *is* `cur`:

```
cur=self.head
```

After that, it builds a new list with updated values, using a "dummy" node as `self.head` (and thus the first `cur`) which is then discarded and only it's `next` is returned. However, I find that code rather confusing and overly complicated (I had a hard time understanding it myself), e.g. the ternary `... if ... else ...` in the last line is redundant as `List` can not be `None` at that point. Also, there's no need in making that a class, since none of its member attributes are used beyond the scope of a single execution of the method.

Instead, you could use a simple function, e.g. using a loop and modifying the original list, or even simpler, recursively creating a new list:

```
def div(lst, d=10):
    first = lst
    while lst:
        lst.value /= d
        lst = lst.next
    return first

def div(lst, d=10):
    return node(lst.value / 10, div(lst.next, d)) if lst else None
```

For easier debugging, you can also add a `__repr__` method to your `node` class:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(%r %r)" % (self.value, self.next)
```